# Prevent Kendo controls from highlighting required fields in red

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I would like to know how avoid the kendo controls have a border in red color when lost focus because I want to show them in red when the user click on save button.

[Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/UlJSOlrZhpcpXC0nkrLj?p=preview)`code`

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/UlJSOlrZhpcpXC0nkrLj?p=preview